# Pacman game - how to fix

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, pacman

I am creating really simple pacman game as a homework. I am working in Visual Studio, in c#. The problem is, when I click run, only the winform shows with nothing on it. Can someone tell me what have I done wrong?

```
namespace pacman
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        Timer timer;
        Pacman pacman;
        static readonly int TIMER_INTERVAL = 250;
        static readonly int WORLD_WIDTH = 15;
        static readonly int WORLD_HEIGHT = 10;
        Image foodImage;
        bool[][] foodWorld;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            foodImage = Properties.Resources.orange_detoure;
            DoubleBuffered = true;
            newGame();
        }

        public void newGame()
        {
            pacman = new Pacman();
            this.Width = Pacman.radius * 2 * (WORLD_WIDTH + 1);
            this.Height = Pacman.radius * 2 * (WORLD_HEIGHT + 1);

            foodWorld = new bool[WORLD_WIDTH][];

            timer = new Timer();
            timer.Interval = TIMER_INTERVAL;
            timer.Tick += new EventHandler(timer_Tick);
            timer.Start();
        }

        void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            timer.Interval = TIMER_INTERVAL - 1;
            if (TIMER_INTERVAL == 0)
            {
                timer.Stop();
            }
            pacman.Move(WORLD_WIDTH, WORLD_HEIGHT);
            Invalidate();
        }

        private void Form1_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (Keys.Up != 0) 
            {
                pacman.ChangeDirection("UP");
            }
            if (Keys.Down != 0)
            {
                pacman.ChangeDirection("DOWN");
            }
            if (Keys.Left != 0)
            {
                pacman.ChangeDirection("LEFT");
            }
            if (Keys.Right != 0)
            {
                pacman.ChangeDirection("RIGHT");
            }
            Invalidate();
        }

        private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            Graphics g = e.Graphics;
            g.Clear(Color.White);
            for (int i = 0; i < foodWorld.Length; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < foodWorld[i].Length; j++)
                {
                    if (foodWorld[i][j])
                    {
                        g.DrawImageUnscaled(foodImage, j * Pacman.radius * 2 + (Pacman.radius * 2 - foodImage.Height) / 2, i * Pacman.radius * 2 + (Pacman.radius * 2 - foodImage.Width) / 2);
                    }
                }
            }
            pacman.Draw(g);
        }
    }
}
```

And here is the class Pacman:

```
namespace pacman
{
    public class Pacman
    {
        public enum dir {UP, DOWN, RIGHT, LEFT}; 

        public float x { get; set; }
        public float y { get; set; }
        public string direction { get; set; }
        static public int radius = 20;
        public double speed { get; set; }
        public bool open { get; set; }
        public Brush brush = new SolidBrush(Color.Yellow);

        public Pacman() {
            this.x = 7;
            this.y = 5;
            this.speed = 20;
            this.direction = Convert.ToString(dir.RIGHT);
            this.open = false;
        }

        public void ChangeDirection(string direct)
        {
            // vasiot kod ovde
            for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) { 

                if(direct == Convert.ToString(dir.RIGHT))
                {
                    direction = "RIGHT";
                }
                if (direct == Convert.ToString(dir.LEFT))
                {
                    direction = "LEFT";
                }
                if (direct == Convert.ToString(dir.UP))
                {
                    direction = "UP";
                }
                if (direct == Convert.ToString(dir.DOWN))
                {
                    direction = "DOWN";
                }
            }
        }

        public void Move(float width, float height)
        {
            if (direction == Convert.ToString(dir.RIGHT))
            {
                x = x + 1;
                if (x > width) {
                    x = 1;
                }
            }
            else if (direction == Convert.ToString(dir.LEFT))
            {
                x = x - 1;
                if (x < 0) {
                    x = 14;
                }
            }
            else if (direction == Convert.ToString(dir.UP))
            {
                y = y + 1;
                if (y > height) {
                    y = 1;
                }
            }
            else if (direction == Convert.ToString(dir.DOWN))
            {
                y = y - 1;
                if (y < 0) {
                    y = 14;
                }
            }
        }

        public void Draw(Graphics g)
        {
            if (!open) {
                g.FillEllipse(brush, 7, 5, 15, 15);
            }
        }   
    }
}
```

It should look like this http://prntscr.com/70e0jt. 
I will be grateful if someone can tell me what should I fix so it finally works..

Comment: After a quick reading..... you're never calling the method `Form1_Paint`...

Comment: Really `Form1_Paint` should either be called by, or the code placed in the protected `OnPaint` override of the base form. I think the OP may have got the override incorrect, or missed creating the Paint event handler in the constructor.

Comment: I checked and fixed that, but now only white background is shown. Nothing else.

Comment: See the edited answer below, the other problem is your `foodWorld` not being initialized completely.

Comment: I wrote this code
         `foodWorld = new bool[WORLD_WIDTH][];

                 for (int i = 0; i < WORLD_WIDTH;i++ )

                {

                   foodWorld[i] = new bool[WORLD_HEIGHT];

                }`
and only this is shown, the images aren't displayed.. 
http://prntscr.com/70e9o3

Comment: Some of them need to be set to true in order for the images to be displayed, read and understand how your drawing code works. When you initialize a bool (or array of bools) they are all false by default.

Comment: How can I set them to be true?

Answer (score 2):

Add this to your constructor:

`this.Paint += Form1_Paint;`

What is happening is that you made a Paint handler, but never assigned the paint event to handle it (that I can see, its possible that the event was assigned in the other partial part of the class).

The other problem is that you did not fully define the "food world" variable, you initialized the first rank, but not the second. You need to fully initialize this and set the booleans inside of it.